# Compressing the final output data into gzip format

Tags: gzip, gzipoutputstream

I am getting the final output data in C++ as a string.....Need to compress that data in gzip format.Can someone tell me the way about how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [zlib](http://zlib.net/).  It's probably already available in your development environment.  (Which for some reason you are keeping a secret in your question.)